# How could I iterate the values in ArrayList in java from java script?

Tags: javascript

I have stored a bulk of objects in an ArrayList and I have set that in the request. Now I want to retrive the values in the Arraylist from my java script. Please help me with the solution

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by you *"...have set that in the request"*? That doesn't immediately make sense.

Comment: I just setting the list object in the request.

Comment: I think he means that he'd put it into the request scope attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JSON](http://www.json.org/java/) to facilitate the exchange of information between Java and Javascript. Libraries are available on both ends.

To put the elements of a `List` into an array, you can use [`Collection.toArray`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize them as javascript first. 
There are 2 ways to do it:

1) Universal way - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library
You just put in your jsp something like this:

```
<script...>
var myArray = <% JSON.Serialize(myArray) %>;
</script>
```

2) Fast and dirty:

```
<script...>
    var myArray = [
    <c:forEach items="${myArray}" var="item">
    {
        name = "<c:out value="${item.name}">",
        text = "<c:out value="${item.text}">"
    },
    </c:forEach>
    ];
</script>
```

Both will result in Javascript like this, and can be used in JS:

```
var myArray = [
{
    name = "Mike",
    text = "Hello world"
},
{
    name = "Max",
    text = "Hi!"
}
];
```

Comment: I have to mention that I would not recommend using JSON for simple arrays (arrays of strings, integers) as it is much easier to do in the "dirty way" with same result, and even better performance.

However, if you have some complex objects that have to be passed to JavaScript - JSON serialization is a way to go.